# Supporting Free Trials with Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

It turns out that Stripe no longer supports free trials for checkout. How can I create a subscription plan that supports a free trial of 7 days in the stripe dashboard?

Comment: Why do you think free trials aren't supported in Checkout? It's listed as a feature on https://stripe.com/payments/checkout.

Comment: I went to Products ---> Add a plan price ---> It says free trial is a legacy feature

Comment: It also mentions the new way to do it, by applying it to the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now recommended to set the trial on the subscription itself instead of the product.

The Stripe Checkout Session [creation call supports a parameter named `subscription_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end), which has parameters that include `trial_period_days`.

Comment: If you want to offer the free trail only to first time subscribers, how do you determine if they are a new subscriber?

Comment: @kezor Checkout has separate modes for *starting* a subscription versus *updating* one already.